# Using Lists Instead of Decorator Pattern?

Tags: java, list, oop, design-patterns, decorator

A Decorator Pattern use case from "Head First: Design Patterns" book made me have this question. I'll try to write it down:

> It's a coffee shop system with some coffees and a lot of condiments
>   you can put in them (for an extra cost), you need to be able to order
>   and charge for a coffee with any condiments the costumer desires, and
>   to avoid having total mayhem (e.g. booleans to keep track of the
>   condiments) Decorator Pattern is used. We have an abstract Beverage
>   class, each type of coffee as concrete components and each condiment
>   as concrete decorators wrapping up a Beverage, like this:
>
> [image: Beverage Class Diagram]
>
> And so we have the following process returning a coffee cost:
>
> [image: Coffee Cost Delegation]

My question is: Why not implement this with Lists instead of the Decorator? We could have a list of Condiment in each Beverage and calculate the cost by iterating through the List. To order a coffee we would just have to instantiate it once and add the desired condiments, avoiding declarations like:

```
// Using second image example
Beverage beverage = new DarkRoast(beverage);
beverage = new Mocha(beverage);
beverage = new Whip(beverage);
```

In addition to that we would have more flexibility for operations like giving discount for a coffee not including it's condiments, once we won't have decorators wrapping up the coffee. This is a matter that have been long studied, I know I'm missing something or maybe I got something wrong, so if you have any thoughts on this I would love to know and discuss it further.

Comment: It's not about the list of discount or taxes you have to subtract or to add at cost. It's about the behaviours you're handling with the decorator pattern. And, believe me, it's harder handle that behaviours with a list instead of with the inheritance.

Comment: Can you give an example using this case? Or maybe another random case? I really cannot imagine a situation in which this occurs.

Comment: This seems like a question which is better for [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). Personally I think that is a terrible use of Decorator (Wikipedia has an example like that too, I think) and can absolutely be solved with a list in a much more manageable way. `java.io.InputStream` is an example of Decorator where it works well. However, you can already see there is a user who disagrees with me, which is why this is probably off-topic for SO.

Comment: This is a pretty contrived example.  Book exercises often are.  Your instinct is good, which shows that you understood the example.  Using inheritance to model condiments would be an anti pattern for me, but as an easy to get example it works.  In real life I would use a list too.  The decorator pattern is best used when you are enhancing the behaviour of an existing object.  For example composing hash maps together or adding a default value to a hash map.

Comment: @PedroPaternostro I think the example given by @Radiodef, [`java.io.InputStream` class and discendents](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/io/overview.html), is pretty interesting and more pertinent.

Comment: Thank you all so much, @Radiodef I will give a deeper look to this case. Anyone have anything to say about it in advance? Why it is a good case of use, what you gain staying true to the decorator and avoiding other approaches, like lists?

Comment: InputStream is good because you are wrapping a lower-level source with higher-level abstractions. You start with a source like byte array, URL, file, etc., then say "Forget about that. Now I just want to get objects out of it" and wrap it in an ObjectInputStream. With InputStream you actually want to more or less forget about the object you are decorating. With the beverage example, at some point you will need to e.g. iterate all of the ingredients and put them in a table or something, and then Decorator is just a clunky linked list.

Comment: @ChrisK Thank you very much, I actually thought I was retarded for not understanding this case! :p

I will definitely search for the pattern on harshmaps, do you have any source on it?

Comment: @Radiodef I appreciate the patience, if you like post your comments as an answer, for it will be more visible to future wanderers. Thanks :)

Comment: @paternostro Raadiodef's reference to InputStream is spot on, BufferedInput is an excellent example of the decorator pattern in action in a situation that is very good design.  I would go with that.  The following resource may also help you: http://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/structural/decorator-design-pattern/

Comment: yes lists fits better than decorator pattern in the example you took, but usually the books try to explain the usuage of a pattern in easy to understand example. Refer my answer below, hope it will be of some help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Decorator` pattern is about decorating ( enhancing ) an object with additional features at runtime.

Suppose you already have a class, lets call it class `A` which implements an interface `IA`. Now if there is a requirement of adding an additional feature for which we want it to have a method ,`someAlignFeatureToA()` which was not there in `A`. Now you have an option of extending the class `A`. Another approach is `Composition` which should be favoured over `Inheritance`. You can wrap the object of class `A` in another class `B` implwmenting the same `Interface` as of `A` i.e. `IA`. This way for the client code it would be easy to accept the object of class B as it has the same interface as of A. (Assumption is the code is well written which depends on the Abstractions (interface `IA`) and not on concrete classes like class `A`).

This way the inheritance chain is not too long and you can add additional features at runtime easily.

**Now coming to your question** : Yes in the example you took in your question, a List fits better, but I feel its the intention of the author to explain usuage of Decorator pattern with an easy example. 
Suppose Coffee is made up of milk, coffee mix and sugar. Coffee mix is further made up of smaller components . Here the solution emerges similar to Composite pattern.

Decorator pattern is design pattern based on Enhancement of Behavior. Java IO streams uses this where behavior (method implementation) is enhanced by the decorating class (one stream is wrapped with another to enhance the previous one)

Comment: Could you please explain in detail how the decorator pattern is helpful and is not an overkill in case of Java IO streams ?

Comment: It would be really interesting to know your idea of achieving the same functionality as per the implementation by java existing io package. How do you think a simple stream may be added the feature of buffer amd so on with an alternate approach to Decorator patter.

Comment: Look at the Coffee shop example in the question. At many places on this page, including your own comment, it is mentioned that the decorator pattern is an overkill for that coffee shop and alternate solutions exist. So, I want to know if its possible to implement IOStreams in another way like we could do for the coffee shop. I'd also like to know why decorator is the best/correct design for IOStreams.

Comment: If I need aethod someAlignFeatureToA(), I would add it directly into class A or create a class AHelper, without extending IA and just call someAlignFeatureToA() from class A. Any problem with these approaches? Your approach seems to be supporting inheritance more than Decorator Pattern.

Comment: @Imad Suppose you had a library in which class A was included, in such a case you would not have been able to add another method. Also modifying exisiting tested code by including another method in an existing class breaks OCP. Now regarding Inheritance, Please re read my answer, I have clearly mentioned not to inherit but to go with the option of composition. Class B compose a reference of class A and B implements same interface as implemented by class A. Class B now can delegate the methods to A by decorating (adding some  extra code if needed).

Comment: Also you do not want the dependent code to change. So adding a class which does not implement the same interface as done by existing class will force dependent code to import another class or interface. this will break existing dependent code.

Answer (score 3):

What you are telling is a way to calculate the total cost of the beverage. In more general terms you are proposing an alternative way to merge & execute the main behavior of each of the derived objects supposed by the Decorator Pattern, by adding up them into a list. And it is not quite an OO approach too.

But the original intent of [Decorator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) goes to a much wider perspective other than that. It is ***Adding extended functionalities to an object dynamically***. Which means I have some object `O1` & I want it to convert it into another object `O2` with extended functionality & yet to be those 2 are interchangeable.

So it is about how we can manage the ***Object Evolution*** against the ***[Object Lifecycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_lifetime)***. Hope you got the idea. :))

Answer (score 3):

An attempt at helping the OP understand that decorators are extending the behaviour which is not so evident by the example in head first book.

Quoting comment by freedev:
*It's not about the list of discount or taxes you have to subtract or to add at cost. It's about the behaviours you're handling with the decorator pattern. And, believe me, it's harder to handle those behaviours with a list compared to inheritance.*

Sharing example from a multi-tenant real E-Commerce application having business in 20 countries (= 20 tenants).

Use Case: Build a Cart (or Basket) object which can be rendered by the UI.

Requirements:

1. The cart view needs to be shown on the cart page as well on the order-review page.
2. The cart can contain some items which are being upgraded/downgraded (you are upgrading your existing broadband plan).

   - So there can be some additional information we may show. (Your upgraded plan will be activated in next x hours. You will be charged a penalty of 2$. Etc.).
   - Also we may show the old plan which will be upgraded/downgraded. (Shown to the user as a cart item but greyed out).
   - Above is again tenant dependent.
3. If the tenant allows inventory constraints, then consider stock status of every item in the cart. But this is not required when we are seeing the cart object on the order-review page, as we have already reserved the cart on checkout.
4. The same cart object also has cart summary inside it (composition), but we don't need the same on the order review page.
5. We also have another view constructed using the same cart object - a lightweight cart view shown when user hovers on the basket icon in the header on UI.

Now this is almost similar to the coffee problem OP described. Too many flavours to handle (tenant specific + page specific behaviour).
What we can do? We can use decorator pattern to decorate our cart with different behaviours as per the requirement.

Possible decorators:

1. CartStatusDecorator
2. CartAdditionalInformationDecorator
3. CartExistingItemsDecorator
4. CartSummaryDecorator

Proceed as below:

1. Construct a basic cart object which has all the minimal required behaviour. For eg, this basic cart should have all cart items with their price, image and quantity.
2. Decide if we need status of the items based on the tenant. If yes, loop in the CartStatusDecorator.
3. Decide if we need to show the 'additional information'. If yes, loop in the CartAdditionalInformationDecorator.
4. Decide if we need to show the older plans. If yes, loop in the CartExistingItemsDecorator.
5. Decide if we want to show summary. Call CartSummaryDecorator.

A top layer can decide based on the tenant and the page which all decorators need to be involved. Imagine doing this with a list of behaviours. It is now evident that list won't be a nice idea.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am too late but I will try my hands on explaining this.

I think the example in Head First book is pretty good attempt to explain this pattern though many people get confused as they find easy alternative, i.e. collection for that example.

I think better example would be food delivery app (WhySoHungry). They have listed multiple offers like

1. Birthday offer
2. Sunday evening offer
3. 10 years of App launch offer.
4. Customers' 100th order offer

and list goes on.

If someone is eligible for multiple offers and WhySoHungry wants them to have all offers applied at the same time then calculation part becomes difficult. This is the best place to apply decorator pattern.

Comment: But as for implementations, I think your `WhySoHungry` app can still be done with a List.

Answer (score 1):

You should distinguish data from behaviour.

A decorator is a layer of indirection dealing with a very specific problem. The data (in terms of types, contracts, protocols etc) stays the same, but you get more flexibility regarding the implementation. With a decorator, you can reuse existing functionality and start adding changes - in conjunction with an adapter in place, you can basically slowly start migrating from pone API to a different one and stay compatible.

Lists should only be responsible for providing access to the contained data in a specific way. Performing tasks on the data / processing the data contained by the lists should be done by function / objects / classes with different responsibilities.

Comment: That last paragraph doesn't make sense to me. How is _handling data_ not performing a task on it?

Comment: I got a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: the terminology and code snippets I use are taken from [this article](https://www.yegor256.com/2015/10/01/vertical-horizontal-decorating.html).

As you noticed, there are two possible designs to "decorate" an object. Both approaches can achieve the same functionality, the main difference is the *context of use*.

## Vertical decorator

```
Numbers numbers = new Sorted(
  new Unique(
    new Odds(
      new Positive(
        new ArrayNumbers(
          new Integer[] {
            -1, 78, 4, -34, 98, 4,
          }
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

This is the most common approach to implement decorators. I almost exclusively implement my decorators in this way because I find it the more "natural" and simple way. It is suited when the number of decorator is not too much (how much is subject to programmer's interpretation).
It is also well-suited when some objects need to be extended dynamically: when it is not known at instanciation time which decorators are needed.

## Horizontal decorator

```
Numbers numbers = new Modified(
  new ArrayNumbers(
    new Integer[] {
      -1, 78, 4, -34, 98, 4,
    }
  ),
  new Diff[] {
    new Positive(),
    new Odds(),
    new Unique(),
    new Sorted(),
  }
);
```

In very rare cases (when the number of decorators starts to grow), I make the design choice to "flatten" the decorators in a list-like structure. This has the advantage to simplify the reading of the code but has the disadvantage to lose the flexibility at runtime: one needs to know at object's creation which decorator to apply (this is especially true in the context of immutability, which I try to foster), so this may be a no-go depending on the application.

In the end, it is only a design decision that you have to make between flexibility & readability.

Answer (score 0):

The way the Head First book has explained it seems to be the common way of teaching the Decorator pattern, but in my opinion, it's not the best way of introducing it. **The gist of the Decorator pattern is NOT just running a list of methods in sequence before a method of our concrete class.**

**The answer to your question:** The Decorator pattern is about turning an object into another similar object but with more capabilities. However, if you pass the Decorators as a list and just run a method of them, you will not get any other objects with increased number of capabilities compared to your original object.

Here's an example of using the list approach as you have proposed:
[image]

For example, you can use it to compress and encrypt some data before writing it to the cloud:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "Hello World";
        CloudStream stream = new CloudStream();
        stream.addDecorator(new CompressedStream());
        stream.addDecorator(new EncryptedStream());
        
        stream.write(data);
    }
```

However, this way, you will not have access to neither the compressed data object, nor the encrypted data object.

In contrast, here's how you can "decorate" a FileInputStream object in Java using an ObjectInptuStream object:

```java
var oistream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream());
```

Now you do have access to the ObjectOutputStream object too, which gives you more [capabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#method_summary) compared to the FileInputStream object.

Answer (score 0):

Just extending same answer given by aderchox above,

Following is snippet using list

```
int main()
{
  string data = "Hello World";
  CouldStream stream = new CloudStream();
  stream.addDecorator(new CompresseStream());
  stream.addDecorator(new EncryptedStream());    
  stream.write(data);
}

void CouldStream::write(string data)
{
  foreach(Decorator dec in _mDecorators)
  {
    if (dec is EncryptedStream)
      dec.setSomethingUniqueFor();
    dec.write(data);
  }
}
```

following is snippet using Decorator Pattern

```
int main()
{
  string data = "Hello World";
  CouldStream stream = new CloudStream();
  stream = new CompresseStream(stream);
  stream = new EncryptedStream(stream);
  stream.setSomethingUniqueFor();
  stream.write(data);
}

void EncryptedStream::write(string data)
{
  doSomethingUniqueFor(data);
  base.write(data);
}
```

here main advantage of decorator pattern is even if CloudStream class is in external library, you can extend functionality by calling decorator class method in your application (main). (of course assumption here is external library allows to extend CloudStream class to write decorators)