# Why should we use decorator pattern?

Tags: oop, object, design-patterns, decorator

I'm watching a course about Design Patterns and the example they used for decorator pattern is the Pizza and Toppings example ( you can find the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707425/12828249) as well).  ***Please have a look at the link to understand my issue***

What I don't like about this pattern as mentioned in the comments of the link I added is that a topping is not a pizza so why should it inherit the pizza class?

The solution I have in my mind is using an array of `PizzaDecorators` objects in a `Pizza` object and use that array to add or remove toppings from a pizza.

Isn't this solution much simpler than using the decorator pattern? Why should we consider using the decorator pattern in a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...a topping is not a pizza so why should it inherit the pizza class?

This comment was answered in the subsequent one: it's simply an issue of naming. Each topping should be named *PizzaWithTopping*.

> ...use an array to add or remove toppings from a pizza?

This solution makes a couple of assumptions.

- Do you own the `Pizza` class? You might be making pizzas for a specific store, where the `Pizza` is determined by a franchise. One way the franchise controls quality is by not allowing individual stores to edit the base `Pizza` code.
- Is a `Pizza` object mutable? Mutability leads to bugs that immutability can avoid. This is a bigger architectural decision than just editing an array.

> Why should we consider using the decorator pattern in a situation like this?

The main advantage of the Decorator pattern over a "collection of enhancements" is that Decorator obeys the [Open-Closed Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/open-closed-principle/info). Decorator applies equally to any class, whether you own it or not, and whether the enhancements are foreseeable or not.

A collection requires that you either,

- See the future and plan ahead by adding a collection (of enhancements with the right interface) to every base class, or...
- Edit the existing base class in violation of the OCP.

In a well-known and relatively small domain like Pizza, this might not be a serious problem. Maybe the toppings never become more complex than adding one-at-a-time through a single API. But with the Decorator, you're covered either way.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565475/using-lists-instead-of-decorator-pattern

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. it really helped me understand this concept